# JS multiple windows, in local

Tags: javascript

following some simple tutorials, from a window **A** I open a second window **B** when a button is clicked.
If from window **B** I ask for *top*, I don't see window **A**, but **B** itself.
I read that the two windows must be under the same domain. I'm doing everything on my PC and the windows are just two HTMLs in a folder. Could this be a problem?

Comment: You may want to try [`opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener). The [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top) property is used for finding the parent window for a frame on a page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is probably the problem.

Try to install simple server like this globally
https://www.npmjs.com/package/httpster

```sh
npm -g install httpster
```

Then run `httpster` command in directory with our files.

Comment: Thanks, I tried and now I'm seeing my project on localhost:3333, but still, when I type "top" in the console in window B, I only get the functions of window B.

Comment: Are both files coming from same origin which is ```localhost:3333``` in your case?

Comment: Yes, they do. But I found a solution, see the answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I try only opener, I get an error ("Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.").
If I try only httpster, I still get the old problem.

If I use both opener and httpster, everything works fine.
Thanks to Peter B and gkucmierz.